# Проблема с запуском файла Python

Tags: python, windows-10, path

При попытке запустить любой файл `.py` ничего не происходит, не выдает ни каких ошибок, просто на секунду открывается консоль открытия файла и сразу же закрывается, даже если код имеет ошибки.

Python добавлен в PATH, и прекрасно работает в CMD.

Python установил на официальном сайте, обновил Visual studio, удалил Avast, частично ограничил антивирус Window - ничего не изменилось.

OC - Windows 10 64Bit

Comment: скачайте PY IDLE официальный, vs ужасно работает с .py файлами https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Не нужно ничего дописывать в заголовок, просто примите ответ который вам помог, галочка слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай файл python_starter.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\open-i]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\open-i\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\py.exe\" -i \"%L\" %*"
```

и слей его в реестр. Если ланчер C:\Windows\py.exe не установлен  - пропиши путь к питону вместо него.

В контектсном меню PY файла появится меню "open-i" и запустив через этот пункт консольное окошко не закроется.

Весь фокус в `-i` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Немного дополню варианты ответа.
Запуск скриптов через IDE это  для всех свои нюансы. Чтобы проверить работу скрипта запустите его через консоль `cmd`. Там будут видны все ошибки если они есть.
Скрипт закрывается мгновенно по двум причинам:

1. Все отработало как надо и скрипт завершил работу. Чтобы предотвратить закрытие добавьте в скрипт:

```py
import os
# ваш код
os.system("pause") # требует нажатие любой клавиши
```

2. В скрипте произошла ошибка и он был завершен преждевременно. Запуск через cmd позволить увидеть где ошибка.

P.S. Под IDE попробуйте VSC (Visual studio code) более легковесная и удобная вещь чем оригинальный Visual studio. Еще популярен Pycharm, мне лично он не нравится но посмотреть стоит.
IDLE на сколько помню ставится с python, к сожалению функциональность не впечатляет. Ну и совсем легковесный вариант sublime text, но надо потратить немного времени на настройку. По выбору IDE все конечно же личное имхо не более.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы будете открыть файл двойным кликом и в коде будет ошибка, то консоль моментально закроеться. Откройте консоль там пропишите cd полныйпутькпапкесфайлом
А потом пишите python имяфайла.py